# .Formula method error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, methods, formula

I tried to run the code below but I keep getting the error "object doesn't support this property or method". Is it because the .Formula refers to the integer i instead of the actual cell? Would really appreciate any feedback! Have been struggling with this for a while now :/ Thank you in advance!

```
Sub GetModelDescr()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range

Worksheets("Stock").Activate

With Worksheets("Stock")
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

   For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
      Set r = rng.Cells(i, 2)
     .Formula "=TRIM(RC[6])&"" ""&MID(RC[-1],7,3)&"" ""&RIGHT(RC[-1],4)"
     .Value2 = .Value2
   Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Formula = .....`  Looks like you are applying the formula to the worksheet though, with your `with` block.  Why set a formula, then set it's value the next line?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I want to convert the formulas to values...but the code doesn't seem to be converting, any advice on how to convert?

Comment: Have you tried with .FormulaR1C1? as you are giving R1C1 references.

Comment: You need to change to `r.formula` first off, but you can just say something like `r.value=trim(r.value) & " " & r.offset(0,-1).value`.....

Comment: Thanks for the tips and feedback! I found a faster way to do it by using   With Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
        .Formula